# Slope Fields of the equation dy/dx=x/y on the point (3,-1) and (1,2)

Tags: calculus

[image]

In this question, I am meant to draw the solution curves that pass through the two points.

This is my work: [image]

However, after solving the differential equation, I found out that it is a hyperbola. Does this mean for the solution curve I should draw a curve that mirrors the curve that have already been drawn or not or should I only keep the curves that pass through the respective points?

Thank you very much.

Comment: If I were grading this question, I would want to see that: a) you know that the integral curves should be tangent to the slope field at every point (which your drawing indicates) and b) that you can solve the differential equation given different initial conditions. Perhaps you could just write the equation you found after solving next to each solution curve.